# Need to replace the subtring of a string prompt with values in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have have a prompt in which there may be %{xyz} which should be replaced by a value and [abc] which shall be replaced by a string.And then the whole string prompt must be displayed with replaced values intact.

For ex- **"Hello Bla Bla %{var1} [var2] Bye %{var3} Testing "** should be displayed as "Hello Bla Bla 23 variable2 Bye 25 Testing" to the user.
Lets say I know the values from the var1 and var2 from a map. I am stuck in how to segregate all the parts and then put all together with replaced values.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::string s = "Hello Bla Bla %{Hi} [testing] Bye %{bla} Die ";
   std::string delimiter = "%";

   size_t pos = 0;

   std::string token,base;
   while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
   {
        token = s.substr(0, pos);
        base.append(token);
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
   }
   base.append(s);
   std::cout << base << std::endl;

  //Need help here for loop condition to traverse the string for several {}
   size_t first = base.find("{");
   size_t last = base.find("}");
   string strVar = base.substr (first+1,last-first-1);
   cout<<strVar<<endl;
   base.replace(first,strVar.length()+2,"25");
   cout<<base<<endl;

   //Need help here for loop condition to traverse the string for several []
   size_t third = base.find("[");
   size_t fourth = base.find("]");
   string strLabel = base.substr (third+1,fourth-third-1);
   cout<<strLabel<<endl;
   base.replace(third,strLabel.length()+2,"variable1");
   cout<<base<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

***EDITED :*** Now I am getting the string prompt without '%' and then I am replacing the first occurrences of '{var1}' and '[variable1]' with values. And then printing the string (base) again. I partially get what is needed. But if I have more than one occurances of {} or [] in the prompt , how to execute the loop in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me. is it the efficient way?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::string s = "Hello Bla Bla %{Hi} [testing] Bye %{bla} Die";

std::string delimiter = "%";

size_t pos = 0;

std::string token,base;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
{
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    base.append(token);
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
base.append(s);
std::cout << base << std::endl;

unsigned int first =0;
unsigned int last=0;
while(last<base.length())
{
    first = base.find("{",first);
    if(first>base.length())
        break;
    last = base.find("}",first);
    string strVar = base.substr (first+1,last-first-1);
    base.replace(first,strVar.length()+2,"25");
    first=last+1;
}
cout<<base<<endl;

unsigned int third=0;
unsigned int fourth =0;
while(fourth < base.length())
{
    third = base.find("[",third);
    if(third>base.length())
       break;
    fourth = base.find("]");
    string strLabel = base.substr (third+1,fourth-third-1);
    base.replace(third,strLabel.length()+2,"variable1");
    third=fourth+1;
}
cout<<base<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do a lot of operations like this, consider using a template engine. In your case the simplest one is sufficient. Take a look at [Plustache](https://github.com/mrtazz/plustache). You will get started within minutes, it's very simple to use. You just create a file containing the string - in your case it would look like:

```
"Hello Bla Bla {{var1}} {{var2}} Bye {{var3}} Testing "
```

Then you load this text from the file and replace the fragments placed in {{ }} easily with whatever you want by using provided template engine function (take a look at the examples provided on the home page to get a grasp). This way you can replace multiple variables and you don't have to worry that you read/write too little or too much by mistake while splitting and concatenating the string (by using a template engine, you don't have to do this at all).

In your case, the code for your task would look as follows (assuming that you put your text in the file of the name Example.txt):

```
PlustacheTypes::ObjectType text_to_be_replaced;
text_to_be_replaced["var1"] = "23";
text_to_be_replaced["var2"] = "variable2";
text_to_be_replaced["var3"] = "25";
Plustache::template_t t;
std::string result = t.render("Example.txt", text_to_be_replaced);
```

The string in the last line (result) now contains the text you want to get:

```
"Hello Bla Bla 23 variable2 Bye 25 Testing"
```

Also, since Plustache comes with open source, you can edit the function:

```
std::string template_t::get_template(const std::string& tmpl)
```

located in template.cpp file so that the text won't need to be placed in a file, but could be read from a string directly, if you don't want to read from a file (if you don't mind that, you can leave this function intact). The library code is not complicated, you will be able to do this very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

How about `std::string::find`?

Take a look at the explanation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

If you found the position, use `std::string::replace` to replace the placeholder with your own text.

Ok, now i understand. After creating the new string `base` you forgot to add everything after the last `%`.

```
while ((pos = str.find(delim)) <= str.length())
{
    base.append(str.substr(0, pos));
    std::cout << base << std::endl;
    str.erase(0, pos + delim.length());
}
// add this line
base.append(str);
std::cout << base << std::endl;
```

Comment: Walle, as you can see I have used find() at places and i can use replace too.The main prob here is that I need to have a logic which would make the string propmt free of "%" symbol first.             And then I would find a substring between {} or [] and replace them.  I am unable to achieve even the first point.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Please see my edited code above. I am getting replaced string at the first occurred places but not for the next of the times. I am not sure what loop condition to execute?